# Restful API in PHP with NGINX. Multiple locations?

Tags: php, rest, nginx

I'm trying to make NGINX handle all my routing. This isn't going to be a huge REST API, so only a few URLs will be available.

```
/directory/api/v1/
```

That will be my base URL for the API. Every request send to that, should automatically be triggered as "REST", if that makes sense.

```
/directory/api/v1/distance/10.95012,-5.192001/5.19288,11.21521
```

Basically that's how one of the URLs will look like. If we were doing rewrite rules (which is what I started with), I would be doing something like:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/directory/api/v1/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /directory/grab.php?method=$1&from=$2&to$3 last;
}
```

That would work great.. for this example. I would easily be able to do the real checking with PHP (if method `distance` is allowed for instance). However, I also want something like this:

```
/directory/api/v1/currentlocation/123
```

Doing that would "break" the `rewrite ^/directory/api/v1/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)` as the regular expression doesn't match.

What would the best approach be? I can't figure out how the `location` works. It would be nice to do something like:

```
location ^~ /directory/api/v1/distance/
    #do something like grab.php?method=distance&from=???&to=???
}
```

Comment: I don't really know nginx much, but the comment still applies. What I would do is make a more generic rule like `^/directory/api/v1/ /directory/grab.php` which should route all requests to the API to my php script. Then in the php script, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine what url/endpoint was called and what endpoint to call. Using your method, every time you want to add something you need to edit the config and restart the webserver. My method, it's just update a php script.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn And then split on `/`, check if [3] (I guess is the method) would be equal to something, then proceed after that? Like `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].split('/')[3] === "distance") ...`? Something like that, obviously.

Comment: pretty much. How you do the splitting and checking what file to include or function to call is up to you. I prefer keeping it a little more abstract by using the URL to find a file that needs to be included if it exists. For example, url: `/directory/api/v1/distance/whatever`, include a file at `api/distance.php`, instantiate a class called `distance` and then call a class method based on the request method (`GET/POST`...etc) passing in whatever arguments after `distance` were included. That method can figure out what to do after that.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's probably what I would have done yeah. My mate gave me a small introduction to Phalcon. Holy moly that works well! Thanks for the idea though.